# NCReport on Mac OS X

Tags: qt

I'm confused, can [NCReport](http://www.nocisoft.com/index.php/home.html) be used in Mac OS X? From the examples given in the Linux files, it seems as if it can support Mac OS X and they even put up [license](http://www.nocisoft.com/index.php/price_and_license.html) fee for anyone using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NCReport just answered my email:

> Yes, the whole NCReport system is
>   MacOSX compatible. Engine and Designer
>   as well. There are several Mac users
>   of NCReport.
>
> Mac customers compile the project from
>   source code to themselves.  MacOSX
>   eval package will available soon.